# Are the Spice models for the TL082 and TL084 wrong?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, texas-instruments, netlists

I am working on a simple phase-lag circuit schematic using LT Spice, and, due to some project specifications, would like to simulate the behavior of the circuit specifically with FET-Input Operational Amplifiers from the TL08x family.

My problem is that I have been trying to add said op amps as new components by downloading the .301 file available online (in places such as the [Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/product/TL082#design-tools-simulation) website) and creating symbols associated to each subcircuit. Everything seems to work just fine for the TL081, **but** I've noticed that the TL082 and TL084 files seem incorrect: they're literally just identical copies of the TL081. The 082 is *supposed* to have 8 ports, since it's essentially an IC with two TL081s inside, but the .301 file only has five ports! Same thing for the TL084.

I've attached screen-captures of the pin distribution I was expecting, based on the datasheet for the TL082, as well as the LTspice files, showing how the subcircuit description *claims* to be for a TL082, but only results in a single, 5 pin op amp. What's going on here? Am I missing something incredibly obvious about how these files are supposed to be used? Did someone just copy-paste the subcircuit description of the TL081 onto the 082 and the 084, upload it to the TI website a decade ago, and leave it there?

[image: Datasheet pin distribution for TL082]
[image: Macromodel subcircuit and port loadout]

Comment: This is actually quite common, and you'll rarely see it the way you originally expected it.  One of the main reasons is this pinout order you see is [almost always] standardized, so you can use a generic SPICE opamp symbol.  In this case, using `opamp2` found near the end of the `[Opamps]` folder in LTspice will work for this library file.  If you want to create a custom subcircuit which includes all the individual amps, you can follow this guide:  https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/ngspice-eeschema.html#multi

Answer (score 3):

Typically SPICE models are per-part. Repeat the model for each part in the package. Using them on a block component (not divided into parts) is not recommended.

LTSpice isn't a full EDA tool anyway, so you miss nothing by using individual TL081s in a model, where you would use -2 or -4s in the actual PCB design.

A downside of this method is you certainly can't get weird interaction effects, like saturation of one amp affecting bias of the other; but that doesn't apply to this type I believe (it's largely a relic of now-long-obsolete types I think), and anyway I doubt a manufacturer would craft a SPICE model so detailed as to include such obscure/deleterious effects anyway.  (Which is also to say: beware that what you get in the model file, need not, and in general does not -- or even, cannot -- reflect the full reality of a given part.)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the datasheet, you will know that they are identical opamps with different numbers in one package. Therefore, they share the same Spice model.